# Order dataframe for given columns

Tags: r

I have data similar to these:

```
data <- data.frame(x1=rexp(10,2),y1=rnorm(10,1),x2=rexp(10,2),y2=rnorm(10,1),x3=rexp(10,2),y3=rnorm(10,1),x4=rexp(10,2),y4=rnorm(10,1))
```

I would like to order all `y1,y2...` variables in increasing order.

I have tried this among others:

```
data[with(data,order(y1,y2,y3,y4,decreasing=FALSE)), ]
```

There is number of SO contribution for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r/1296745#1296745) about order, yet I cannot make it work.

Comment: What is the problem with the one in the link?

Comment: Only the first column `y1` is order not the rest `y2...`

Comment: Should the order of the values in the `x` columns change too?

Comment: I think you could use `do.call(order,  c(data[grep('^y', names(data))], decreasing=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun: I like your solution, if you would submit it, I would accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sven. Yes indeed, since it is order and not sort, I would like to (I have to) preserve the x and y relationship. So the x changes correspondingly to y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table` package you can either sort by reference and pass several variable names at once to the `setorder` function (this function isn't mentioned in the above link)

```
library(data.table)
setorderv(setDT(data), grep("^y\\d+", names(data), value = TRUE))
```

If you want decreasind order you can specify the `order`, e.g.,

```
setorderv(setDT(data), grep("^y\\d+", names(data), value = TRUE), order = -1L)
```

The nicest thing about it, is that you can pass a whole vector into `order` that will sort each column differently, for example

```
indx <- c(1L, -1L, -1L, 1L)
setorderv(setDT(data), grep("^y\\d+", names(data), value = TRUE), order = indx)
```

While everything is done by reference (without creating copies using `<-`)

Comment: How do you change the order to `decreasing=TRUE` here?

Comment: That is very informative.  Will definitely steal these ideas :-)

Comment: @akrun It is pitty @Matt didn't add this to his `data.table` answer in the link mentioned by the OP

Comment: You could update in that link or post as a new solution there.

Comment: This is very handy. I decided to accept David your solution as in my opinion is marginally better and possibly usefully to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
indx <- do.call(order, c(data[grep('^y', names(data))], decreasing=TRUE))
data[indx,]
```

By default, the option is `decreasing=FALSE`.  If that is what you wanted, just do

```
indx <- do.call(order, data[grep('^y', names(data))])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cited solution does exactly what it is supposed to do - sort first on y1, then (for same y1-values) on y2, and so on.

If you want to have each x-y pairs sorted independently, you have to break up the data.frame.

```
data.frame(data[with(data,order(y1,decreasing=FALSE)),c('x1', 'y1') ],
       data[with(data,order(y2,decreasing=FALSE)),c('x2', 'y2') ],
       data[with(data,order(y3,decreasing=FALSE)),c('x3', 'y3') ],
       data[with(data,order(y4,decreasing=FALSE)),c('x4', 'y4') ])
```