# Column Names in Order

Tags: r, sorting

In the following code snippet, data is ordered by `col1` followed by `col2`, I want to make the order statement generic so that if data has additional columns e.g. `col3` the same order statement will work to sort the data by the additional columns in the order they appear (so, order by `col1`, then `col2`, then `col3`). Essentially need to make order statement dynamic

```
df <- cbind(c("c","a","b"))

df <- cbind(df, c(2,3,1))

df <- as.data.frame(df)

names(df)[1] <- "col1"

names(df)[2] <- "col2"

df[order(df$col1, df$col2),]
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026579/order-dataframe-for-given-columns/) could be useful

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df[do.call(order, as.list(df)), ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. With this I was able to get to below

df <- cbind(c("c","a","a"))
df <- cbind(df, c(2,1,1))
df <- cbind(df, c("n","m","o"))
df <- as.data.frame(df)

names(df)[1] <- "col1"
names(df)[2] <- "col2"
names(df)[3] <- "col3"


order_by_cols <- 3
df[do.call(order, as.list(df[,c(1:order_by_cols)])), ]